# Help with switch case

Tags: java

This is my program, it will count all the spaces, all the letter a,e,s,t upper or lower cases but I'm having an error when compiling, it give me that one of my variable is not initialized.

Could someone take a look and tell me

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      String phrase;    // a string of characters
      int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
      int length;       // the length of the phrase
      char ch;          // an individual character in the string
        int countA=0,countE=0,countS=0,countT=0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Print a program header
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Character Counter");
      System.out.println ();

      // Read in a string and find its length
      System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
      phrase = scan.nextLine();
      length = phrase.length();


        // Initialize counts
      countBlank = 0;

      // a for loop to go through the string character by character

        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)  
        {
    if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') countBlank++;
        }
    switch(ch) {
    case 'a':
    case 'A': countA++;
    break;

    case 'e':
    case 'E': countE++;
    break;

    case 's':
    case 'S': countS++;
    break;

    case 't':
    case 'T': countT++;
    break;

    }

      // Print the results
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
        System.out.println ("Number of a: " + countA);
        System.out.println ("Number of e: " + countE);
        System.out.println ("Number of s: " + countS);
        System.out.println ("Number of t: " + countT);
      System.out.println ();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give us the error that shows up?

Comment: Count.java:42: variable ch might not have been initialized
 switch(ch) {
        ^
1 error

Comment: looking at the code, i could say that `char ch` is uninitialized

Comment: So, where do you assign to `ch`?

Comment: You don't have to declare all variables at the top of the function in Java like you do in C89. It's much safer to declare the variable at the point you initialise it.

Comment: @Tuan: generally speaking, you should up-vote answers that are helpful and accept the answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues: first the current character is never assigned to ch and second the switch statement is not inside for your for loop.

Comment: Ahhh i see, if i nested the switch under the for loop, it works and i can then use ch=phrase.charAt(i); thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You write

```
switch(ch)
```

but the variable `ch` is never assigned a value.

Answer (score 2):

You have "switch(ch)" but you never assigned it a value. You declared it using "char ch;" but that's not enough.

Maybe you want to do:

```
ch = phrase.charAt(i);
```

inside of your loop.

So your combined code can look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Count
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      String phrase;    // a string of characters
      int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase
      int length;       // the length of the phrase
      char ch;          // an individual character in the string
        int countA=0,countE=0,countS=0,countT=0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Print a program header
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Character Counter");
      System.out.println ();

      // Read in a string and find its length
      System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
      phrase = scan.nextLine();
      length = phrase.length();


        // Initialize counts
      countBlank = 0;

      // a for loop to go through the string character by character

        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
        {
            if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' ') countBlank++;
            ch = phrase.charAt(i);

                switch(ch) {
                    case 'a':
                    case 'A': countA++;
                    break;

                    case 'e':
                    case 'E': countE++;
                    break;

                    case 's':
                    case 'S': countS++;
                    break;

                    case 't':
                    case 'T': countT++;
                    break;
                }
        }


      // Print the results
      System.out.println ();
      System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
        System.out.println ("Number of a: " + countA);
        System.out.println ("Number of e: " + countE);
        System.out.println ("Number of s: " + countS);
        System.out.println ("Number of t: " + countT);
      System.out.println ();
    }

}
```

Comment: should i do ch = phrase.charAt(i); at the very beginning or right before the switch?

Comment: actually if i do ch = phrase.charAt(i); then i get an error that i was not found

Comment: did you have it inside of the loop? i moved it all into the loop, and it works.

Comment: Yea the problem was that my switch wasn't inside the for loop, i've moved it in and now it works. I didnt notice that at first, thanks.

Comment: Also if i wanted to keep it running after the first phrase was enter and have the user quit manually using a string. Where would I place the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

change Ur for statement like this , the switch must be included in the for , and the ch should be initialized to be the i-th character .

```
 for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)  
                {
                if(phrase.charAt(i) == ' ')
                    {
                        countBlank++;
                    }
                ch = phrase.charAt(i);

                    switch(ch)
                    {
                        case 'a':
                        case 'A': countA++;
                        break;

                        case 'e':
                        case 'E': countE++;
                        break;

                        case 's':
                        case 'S': countS++;
                        break;

                        case 't':
                        case 'T': countT++;
                        break;

                    }
                }
```